# Scala tuple memory overhead

Tags: scala, memory-management

What is additional memory cost of Tuple[Int, Int] ie. (1, 2) over two Ints without Tuple ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JVM overheads tend to be 16 to 24 bytes per object (32-bit and 64-bit respectively, though compressed pointers can make the latter smaller).  `Tuple2` is specialized on `Int`, which means it stores the values in fields, so you have 8 bytes for two ints as compared to 8+16=24 or 8+24=32 for (1,2).  If you use a similar non-specialized collection (or use Tuple2 for something that it is not specialized on, like `Char`), then you need pointers to objects, and you *may* need the objects depending on whether they can be pre-allocated (arbitrary integers, no; arbitrary bytes, yes; arbitrary chars, maybe).  If yes, then you just need the pointer and it's 8+16=24 or 16+24=40 bytes; if no, you need three objects, so it's 16+8+2*(16+4) = 64 and 24+16+2*(24+4) = 96 respectively.

Bottom line: objects use a *lot* more memory than primitive types, usually 3-4x, but sometimes over 10x.  If you are short on memory, pack as much as you can into arrays.  For example:

Bad for memory usage:

```
val a = (1 to 10000).map(x => (x,x.toString.length)).toArray
```

Good for memory usage:

```
val b = ((1 to 10000).toArray, (1 to 10000).map(_.toString.length).toArray)
```

If you're really tight on memory, you can then write iterators and other wrappers that let you index things as if they were an array of tuples instead of a tuple of arrays.  It's a bit of a pain, but if you're really short on memory it can be worth it.

Comment: Specialization doesn't seem to have any effect on fields. Using `:javap -p scala.Tuple2` (from REPL), I see the specialized methods, but still just two fields of type `Object`.

Comment: @Daniel - That's the unspecialized version.  Try `:javap -v scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp` (does work from REPL if you prepend scala.).